# Is there any way to programatically set "Always open=true" for a specific mime type for Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

Basically my customer wants (much against my advice) to force all their users to have "Always open .docx" files enabled in Internet Explorer after the product has been installed on their computer. This so that they won't be bothered with clicking "Open" after clicking a .docx link. Is there any way I can achieve that? Is this controlled by a registry key perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer in [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/57402307-1cbd-49db-aabd-65c2fea19ed9/ie9-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt). Works for IE10. Yet I would advice anyone reading this to think twice about implementing this. Note that the user has the power to set this setting himself in the GUI (Ctrl+J), but forcing it upon him should never be done.

With that piece of warning, here's a registry file which sets the key needed to always open .docx files when downloading in IE:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
"Word.Document.12"=hex:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one case where I would have to report to my customer that I'm unable to find a solution even if I knew one.

With the current amount of attacks using carefully crafted documents, automatically opening *anything* that comes from a browser is like handing over your company to criminals with a kiss.